# Pandas DataFrame, replace value of a column by the value of an other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My boosting_df Pandas DataFrame is the following one:

```
  sku   boost1 boost2 boost3  boost4
0   a  ffffdfg      a   fggg  replace
1   b      fff    fff    fff  replace
2   c      ddf      b    ddf  replace
3   d     dfgd   dfgd    d    replace
```

for each line, if the value of 'sku' is the same as the value boost1 or boost2 or boost3 then I want to replace the matching value by the value inside boost4

example:

```
  sku   boost1 boost2 boost3
0   a  ffffdfg replace   fggg
1   b      fff    fff    fff
2   c      ddf      b    ddf
3   d     dfgd   dfgd    replace
```

I tried:

```
boosting_df.loc[boosting_df['boost1'] == boosting_df['sku'], 'boost1'] = boosting_df['boost4']
boosting_df.loc[boosting_df['boost2'] == boosting_df['sku'], 'boost2'] = boosting_df['boost4']
boosting_df.loc[boosting_df['boost2'] == boosting_df['sku'], 'boost3'] = boosting_df['boost4']
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (0,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Boolean mask has to be applied to both side of the assignment, so that the dimension and index will match:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    col = 'boost{}'.format(i)
    mask = (df['sku'] == df[col])
    df.loc[mask, col] = df.loc[mask, 'boost4']
```

Output:

```
  sku   boost1   boost2   boost3   boost4
0   a  ffffdfg  replace     fggg  replace
1   b      fff      fff      fff  replace
2   c      ddf        b      ddf  replace
3   d     dfgd     dfgd  replace  replace
```

Comment: `.loc` should also be perfectly fine, does this not give the same output as `ix`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake -- `.loc` is perfectly fine. Thanks for pointing out :)